# How does ENTRYPOINT Docker directive react when extending images

Tags: jenkins, docker

I want to know does react the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction from Dockerfiles when heritage happens :

Let's say for example I have an **image called** : [*jenkins*](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker)

```
FROM java:8-jdk
RUN ...
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]
```

By running this image, the `ENTRYPOINT` directive will start and install the application as expected

Let's say now that I want to **extend this image** with a new Dockerfile, I call it : *jenkins-custom*

```
FROM jenkins

# enable start tls
RUN echo "JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS=\"-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true\"" >> /etc/default/jenkins
RUN chown jenkins:docker /etc/default/jenkins
```

Should I consider that :

1. the *jenkins* entrypoint is triggered after my new lines.
2. entrypoint will be trigered before my new lines.
3. entrypoint will not be triggered.

In my example, I am trying to activate STARTTLS in default Jenkins Docker image, should I just restart the process in the second image ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commands in `ENTRYPOINT` run when you execute `docker run`. However, commands in `RUN` are executed when you run `docker build`.

In your case, what's going to happen is that when you `docker build` the image, a new Jenkins configuration file is generated, and then when you `docker run` it, `tini` is launched, and in turns execute the `jenkins-entrypoint.sh`.

---

If what you're trying to do is change the Jenkins configuration and nothing else, what you have here is good.

Comment: I couldn't be sure enough, thanks for reminding me !

Comment: @BigDong Just keep in mind that Docker actually outputs what it does when you run `docker build`, so you should see that Jenkins does **not** start at that point ; )